Overlapping 2 images in HTML
I have tried everything AI can seem to come up with to solve this with no joy .
I'm trying to create an HTML email template in MS Dynamics 365 Sales. The email should consist of a main image that is just a png hosted by email academy to leverage the Cloudflare CDN plus a footer image (also hosted by email academy). I need the footer image to sit on top of the main image at the bottom by somewhere in the range of 10-20px. Meaning the bottom of the footer image should sit about 10-20px ABOVE the bottom of the main image. I can NOT get the stupid thing to overlap AT ALL! And I don't have anywhere NEAR enough hair left to keep pulling it out! 
This is about as close as I've gotten but the footer is still not overlapping on the main image:
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Stitched Image</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: 'Times New Roman';
            font-size: 12pt;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .image-container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .main-img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            display: block;
        }
        .footer-img {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            top: -10px; /* Adjust this value to control the overlap */
            margin-bottom: -10px; /* Adjust this value to ensure the container height is correct */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image-container">
        <!-- Main Image -->
        <img class="main-img" src="https://cdn.emailacademy.com/user/167e7bab7a2c486a559676efd3e1ad6cea8bc9f91874d8335452588bd4de95d0/Taking%20Off2024_07_30_16_51_10.png" alt="Main Image" />

        <!-- Footer Image with Image Map -->
        <img class="footer-img" src="https://cdn.emailacademy.com/user/167e7bab7a2c486a559676efd3e1ad6cea8bc9f91874d8335452588bd4de95d0/Footer2024_07_30_18_03_34.png" usemap="#footer-map" alt="Footer Image" />

        <!-- Image Map -->
        <map name="footer-map">
            <area shape="circle" coords="92,54,49" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/ariaconsulting" alt="LinkedIn" target="_blank" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="373,54,48" href="https://pinterest.com/ariaconsulting" alt="Pinterest" target="_blank" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="652,52,49" href="https://www.facebook.com/ariaconsulting" alt="Facebook" target="_blank" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="928,54,47" href="https://www.instagram.com/ariaconsulting" alt="Instagram" target="_blank" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="398,107,666,135" href="mailto:info@ariaconsulting.net" alt="Email" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="693,106,982,137" href="https://ariaconsulting.net" target="_blank" />
        </map>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


I've tried everything the AI helpers could come up with. None of the approaches has worked to get the footer image to basically nest in the main image container at the bottom.
The need is to stitch together the 2 images such that the footer image sites inside the main image container roughly 10-20px above the bottom of the main image.
In a word: HELP!
Thanks.

This question is similar to: Position image on top of another in email html using css. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
